# Textual schedules from data object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dates and with it a value that represents how many patients a doctor is scheduled to talk to that day. I want to sift through the data to produce a textual response as to which days they have partially filled, like under 2 people for that date, and days that are clear and in the future for the doctor. Like the following **week/month**.

```
    doctorScheduleAnalysis function(){
      let data =     [
     {date: "2023-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", value: 2}, 
     {date: "2023-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", value: 4}, 
     {date: "2023-10-24T23:00:00.000Z", value: 1}
    ];
      
const partials = data.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.value <= 2;
});
console.log("partials", partials);


const selectMostRecent = dates =>
  dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))[0];

console.log(selectMostRecent(data));
      
      
        let approximateDate = "post-16th June";
        let clearDates = "10th and 12";
    
        let analysis = "Schedule a call with <span>Dr name</span>. <span>Dr name</span> has a clear schedule "+ approximateDate +". They have some availability on "+clearDates+". Please select a day and a time.";
        return analysis;
      }
```

```js
         function doctorScheduleAnalysis(){
          let data =     [
         {date: "2023-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", value: 2}, 
         {date: "2023-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", value: 4}, 
         {date: "2023-10-24T23:00:00.000Z", value: 1}
        ];
          
    const partials = data.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.value <= 2;
    });
    console.log("partials", partials);
    
    
    const selectMostRecent = dates =>
      dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))[0];
    
    console.log(selectMostRecent(data));
          
          
            let approximateDate = "post-16th June";
            let clearDates = "10th and 12";
        
            let analysis = "Schedule a call with <span>Dr name</span>. <span>Dr name</span> has a clear schedule "+ approximateDate +". They have some availability on "+clearDates+". Please select a day and a time.";
            
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = analysis;
            //return analysis;
          }
          
          doctorScheduleAnalysis()
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```